# Folder in read-only mode after movement

Tags: html, internet-explorer, activex, activexobject

Below code to move the folder from one place to another. This code will move the folder. But, the outcome leaves the folder in a read-only state. I tried moving the folder instead of copy-delete. Even that does not help in here. How to overcome this.?

```
function CopyFolder(){
    try{
        var fileSystem = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var sourceFolder = document.getElementById("source").value;
        var DestnFolder = document.getElementById("destn").value;
        var myFolder;
        if (!fileSystem.FolderExists(DestnFolder))
        {
            fileSystem.CreateFolder(DestnFolder);
        }
        myFolder = fileSystem.GetFolder(sourceFolder);
        myFolder.Copy(DestnFolder);
        //myFolder = fileSystem.GetFolder(sourceFolder);
        //myFolder.Delete();
        myFolder = null;
        fileSystem = null;
        return DestnFolder;
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert("error in moving Incident folder to Zip");
    }
}
```

It would be very helpful, If there is any code to remove all dependencies or clear all object which holds any relationship with the fodler(Or content in fodler).

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @Java_User : I am not getting any error. But the folder which is copied to destination location is in readonly mode.